# How to serialize foreign key from model X in model Y, where model X has the relation to model Y?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to serialize my Contracts view in my Registration view.

I understand how to do it if there was a foreign key in the Registration model relating the Contract model, but in this case there is a relation from the Contract model to the Registration model.

I need to do this in a bigger project, this is just a simple boiler plate.
Basically, I want my output to be this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "client": "John Doe",
        "contract": {
            "id": 1,
            "client": "John Doe",
            "name": "New Identity",
            "registration": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "client": "Jane Doe",
        "contract": {
            "id": 2,
            "client": "Jane Doe",
            "name": "Identity theft",
            "registration": 2
        }
    }
]
```

Models:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Registration(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Contract(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    registration = models.ForeignKey(Registration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Viewsets:

```
class ClientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer


class RegistrationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Registration.objects.all()
    queryset = queryset.select_related("client")
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer


class ContractViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contract.objects.all()
    queryset = queryset.select_related("registration").prefetch_related(
        "client"
    )
    serializer_class = ContractSerializer
```

Serializers:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = "__all__"


class ContractSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = NameSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        fields = "__all__"


class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = NameSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still query contracts using: `register_obj.contract_set.all()` which will return all the rows that have the foreign key pointing to the selected `register_obj`.

And your serializer should be like this:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = NameSerializer()
    contracts = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_contracts(self, obj):
        # if you need all the contracts in a list:
        return ContractSerializer(obj.contract_set.all(), many=True).data

        # or if you just need the first one:
        return ContractSerializer(obj.contract_set.first()).data
        # you can also filter the query
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked great. What I've tried before was to add a property in the model. The field actually shows in the serializer but didn't have any data.

Comment: Just tried that method in the real project and it improved the serializer response time by a lot.